# Wrap each pytest test function into try-except

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I want to wrap each of my test functions into a try-except block to execute code in the except block. This code should only be executed if the test is failing.

I want to achieve this without altering the test functions, but instead use some kind of decorator/fixture. Unfortunately I can not find any examples.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
def test_1():
    some_method_that_might_throw_an_exception()
```

I have multiple tests and all of them should run a function `run_only_if_exception_was_thrown()` if an exception was thrown by the test.
I want to achieve this without using a try/catch block inside the tests.

My current approach is to use `sys.last_value` inside a fixture to check if an exception was thrown:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fix():
    yield X()
    try:
        if sys.last_value:
            # error
    except AttributeError:
            # no error thrown

def test1(fix):
    some_method_that_might_throw_an_exception()
```

Comment: Could you add an example what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
def test_dec(test_func):
    def test_wrapper(fix):
        try:
            test_func(fix)
        except:
            run_only_if_exception_was_thrown(fix)
            # re-raise exception to make the test fail
            raise

    return test_wrapper
```

Then in your test suite:

```
...
@test_dec
def test_one(fix):
    # test code
```

Comment: How would this code look if `test_one` had a fixture argument?

Comment: I edited my answer. The decorator handles arbitrary parameters.

Comment: I want to use the object passed to the test function inside the decorator. e.g. `run_only_if_exception_was_thrown(fix)` Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Oh, I see. Edited my answer.

Comment: @user1211030 Could you explain what you were using this for? I'm just curious.